# How to match a C-style array in Google Mock

Tags: c++, googletest

Given the following example

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <stdint.h>


using namespace ::testing;

class Tested
{
public:
    virtual void setArray(const uint32_t[3]) {};
};

class Tested_mock: public Tested
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(setArray, void(const uint32_t[3]));
};

class TestRunner: public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    StrictMock<Tested_mock> t;
};

TEST_F(TestRunner, test)
{

    uint32_t a[3] = {1UL, 2UL, 3UL};

    EXPECT_CALL(t, setArray(_)).With(ElementsAreArray(a));

    t.setArray(a);
}
```

i don't understand why i'm not able to compile this snippet while changing the argument to `uint32_t*` works. Does Gmock have a problem with fixed-size-array arguments ?

You could find the compilation output here https://pastebin.com/72b4iYqs

Comment: `uint32_t a[] = {1UL, 2UL, 3UL};`

Comment: i tried that already with `ElementsAreArray(a,3)`. it does not work ...

Comment: Does this work? `uint32_t a[3] = {1, 2, 3};`

Answer (score 1):

Late to party but I had the same issue.
The problem is that the testing framework also wants to know the size of the actual array to check if it's the same as expected.
In the end I ended up defining my own Matcher that takes the size as an argument:

```
MATCHER_P2(FixedSizeArrayMatches, expected, elements, "")
{
    return memcmp(arg, expected, elements * sizeof(expected[0])) == 0;
}
```

This can then be used like this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(t, setArray(FixedSizeArrayMatches(a, 3));
```